# JsonObject returns {"empty":false} in API response

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have the following code on my project:

```
@SessionScope
@RestController
public class cdaDisplayTool {
    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(cdaDisplayTool.class);

    @PostMapping(path = "/display_XML", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    protected JSONObject display_XML(@RequestBody ObjectNode model,HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
            String cda_base64 = null;
            String htmlcda = null;
            JSONObject results = new JSONObject();
            
            if (model.has("cda_base64")) {
                cda_base64 = model.get("cda_base64").asText();
                byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cda_base64);
                String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);
                String cda_xml = decodedString;
                htmlcda = CdaXSLTransformer.getInstance().transform(cda_xml, "en-GB",
                        "/dispense");
            }
            
            LOG.info("cdahtml: "+ htmlcda);
            results.accumulate("status", 200).accumulate("data", htmlcda);
            return results;
        
    }

}
```

When I Log `htmlcda` parameter, I get the html string correctly. However, in response `results` JsonObject I get {"empty":false}. Any help please?

Comment: @Nemanja, thank you! You can add it as a response to accept it.

Comment: @Zion Ok, I added it as response :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Spring boot uses jackson as default serializer** and you're trying to return JSONObject itself. **Jackson does not know how to serialize it**. If you need to return JSON, you can put your properties in `Map`, and return it. Otherwise, you can return `results.toString()`, or `ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(result.toString())`